# my text messaging app is suddenly displaying all my contacts with no conversations

Tags: samsung

My text messaging app instead of just displaying all my recent text messaging conversations has suddenly included ALL my contacts. My recent SMS conversations are swallowed up in the midst of all my contacts. How do I delete these contacts  with whom I have no text message conversations from my message app? I want to keep the phone numbers in my contacts but I don't want the contacts stuck in the middle of my text message conversations...help!